# How to navigate the component from NVD3 Callback in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, nvd3.js, angular4-router

I have implemented `NVD3` Charts in Angular 4. written an on Click event inside a callback function, on click of the chart I am trying to navigate to another component but I am unable to navigate.

**Code :**

```
import { Router} from '@angular/router';
export class MyNewComponentComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(public router: Router)
  {

  }
 this.options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'discreteBarChart',
      height: 450,
      margin : {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 50,
        left: 55
      },

      x: function(d){return d.label;},
      y: function(d){return d.value;},
      showValues: true,
      valueFormat: function(d){
        return d3.format(',.4f')(d);
      },
      duration: 500,
      xAxis: {
        axisLabel: 'X Axis'
      },
      yAxis: {
        axisLabel: 'Y Axis',
        axisLabelDistance: -10
      },
      callback: function(chart){ 
        chart.discretebar.dispatch.on('elementClick', (angularEvent,e) => {
             console.log("Inside click"); 
                            this.router.navigate(["/app-new-component2"]); 


        });

      }

    }
  }
```

}

I am getting this error in Console. Could not able find the component reference to redirect.
[image]

Awaiting Suggestions. Thanks In Advance ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So your problem is right here

```
  callback: function(chart){ // note the callback function
    chart.discretebar.dispatch.on('elementClick', (angularEvent,e) => {
         console.log("Inside click"); 
         this.router.navigate(["/app-new-component2"]); 
    });

  }
```

So where your callback is, you are using an es5 `function()` which means anything within that function will not hold the global scope `this` and instead create a new scope. So in this case when you do `this.router.navigate` your not referring to the component (global `this`) your referring to the functions scope `this` which does not have a `router`. So what you want to do is this,

```
  callback: (chart) => { 
    chart.discretebar.dispatch.on('elementClick', (angularEvent,e) => {
         console.log("Inside click"); 
         this.router.navigate(["/app-new-component2"]); 
    });

  }
```

using an ES6 (fat arrow) function `() => {}` will keep the global scope `this` which will let you use your router.